# Does shopify provide access tokens for unpublished apps?

Tags: php, api, shopify, shopify-app

So, I made a shopify app from my developers account (linked to the code running in my localhost.) and installed it on my development store(via link generated by code on my localhost). Everything seems to be working (The sha-256 hash-check is successful.) except after I make a post request to the `admin/oauth/access_token` page; it is sending back an empty result instead of a json string with access token in it. Is it because I am asking access token for an unpublished app? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When someone installs your app you receive a temporary access token that you can exchange for a permanent token by sending over your public api key, private api key, and the temporary token they give you and you should receive back a response with a permanent access_token. Im doing the exact same thing with a private unpublished app and it works so you should be good you might just be doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks. It worked after I set the SSL_VERIFYPEER to false in the CURL request. I am however concerned if it has security vulnerabilities on doing so!

Answer (score 1):

The published state of an App has nothing to do with tokens. Your oAuth code is responsible for all problems with correctly receiving a token.

Comment: Thanks. It worked after I set the SSL_VERIFYPEER to false in the CURL request. I am however concerned if it has security vulnerabilities on doing so!

Comment: You probably don't want to mess with the encryption. Something like that mis-configured on your end could expose you to all sorts of grief!

Comment: Yea, perhaps. But I saw the function shopify_call here using that for making other requests  https://github.com/nyalex/shopify-generating-api-token-guide and it didn't work for me without setting the option.